# Installing titling.sty onto an offline Windows machine

Tags: packages, miktex, offline

I'm trying to compile a file for which I need `titling.sty`:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `titling.sty` not found.

The two biggest issues are 1) it's on a Windows machine (I'm really only "comfortable" with the Unix command line) and 2) the machine cannot be connected to the internet (so automatic approaches are impossible).

Assuming the error means I'm missing a package and following some related advice (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252903/knit-pdf-file-from-rstudio)), I downloaded the file [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titling.zip), transferred it to the offline machine, and unzipped it, then tried to run:

```
latex titling.ins
```

But this gave me an error (given I can't copy-paste, I'm including what I think may be relevant):

> `********************************************************`
>
> `* No Configuration file found, using default settings. *`
>
> `********************************************************`
>
> `!`
>
> `**************************************************`
>
> `* Could not find your \batchfile=titling.ins.`
>
> `**************************************************.`
>
> `\processbatchFile ...****************************}`
>
> `\fi \else \ifDefault \Msg ...`
>
> `1.1092 \process@first@batchfile`

I have no idea how to proceed from this.

How can I install `titling.sty` on this machine?

Comment: Which distribution do you use?

Comment: titling is in both miktex and texlive so you should not have to install it by hand like this

Comment: I believe the compiler is trying to use `pdflatex`, but it's through miktex. Oddly enough I was able to get the `latex titling.ins` command to work using the Git Bash installed with Git. Now I need to figure out where to put the damn .sty file. But first trying @DavidCarlisle's advice and re-installing miktex first.

Comment: you can always put the .sty file in the working directory alongside the document, but updating miktex via its package manager thing (I don't use miktex) should install it automatically, re-installing miktex shouldn't be needed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as I mentioned this is offline, so I can't update via package manager. Re-installing MiKTeX didn't fix anything, and indeed I don't see `titling` in `/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/` which is where I presume it should be. Copying `titling.sty` to the document folder for now, thanks!

Comment: oh yes I skimmed over the offline bit, sorry:-)

Comment: Can you download files from CTAN using  some other machine?

Comment: If the machine if offline and you need to use TeX regularly on it, install TeX Live as it will install everything by default. You can put the `.sty` in your working directory with the `.tex` file if you are just doing this as a one-off.

Comment: The correct place to install additional packages that were not in the distribution — in this case, where online installation is impossible — would be the personal TeX directory C:\texmf\tex\latex\titling or Computer\System\Users\your~name\texmf\tex\latex\titling as described in http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/personal.html#winpers (this means it's available globally, rather than just in the document folder).

Comment: Incidentally, what directory did you type the latex titling.ins command in? I discovered that MikTeX won't let you do this within its own installation folders — you have to do it somewhere else (eg C:\temp) and copy the resulting .sty file to where you need it.

Comment: @PeterFlynn I just opened up the terminal and did `latex F:/path/to/titling.sty`. Perhaps it was that I was fetching from another folder?

Comment: Possible...I'm not a Windows user so I don't know the full details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have other means to transfer files to the machine:

1. Go to some CTAN mirror to the miktex package folder
   http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages.
2. Download all packages you want to install (e.g. with wget).
3. Download also the databases `miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma` and `miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma`
4. Put everything in one folder (outside miktex) on your offline windows.
5. Start the package manager and choose this folder as "local repository".
6. Install the packages.

Be aware that the package manager will show all packages recorded in the database but that you naturally can only install the packages you actually downloaded.

Also keep the databases (the miktex-zz-files) and the packages in sync.

Comment: It seems using this approach messed up my MikTeX installation in a strange way, such that using `knit` on an Rmd document failed (error same as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856362/pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-error-43-pdflatex-the-memory-dump-file), but different root cause), but compiling from TeXworks worked without error. Couldn't figure out what's going on, but a clean uninstall/reinstall/restart actually fixed my initial issue (compiling now works even without the .sty file stored locally)