# MikteX portable version 2.9 requiring package file .sty and not working with .dtx

Tags: packages, miktex, dtx

I downloaded this morning the latest version of MikteX portable (2.9) on Windows to update my old version (dating back from 2013 I would say). I have a personal directory with some additional packages I use (with the right architecture, e.g. myfilefortex\tex\latex). I set the MikteX options to install those packages (by adding the path of my personal directory as a root and refreshing the FNDB). I had already used those packages with my old MikTex portable version and it was perfectly working. When I compile with TexMaker (pdfLatex) and my new MikteX version, it doesn't find the file 'subcaption.sty'. I checked, I only have a 'subcaption.dtx' file, which was working before... and the CTAN package 'caption' containing 'subcaption' only provides the .dtx file (and not the .sty file). And concerning the installation of a .dtx file, the .ins file which could help (I read that in some others answers) is not provided with the package.

Could anyone help me with this issue please ? Is there a way to get a .sty file from a .dtx ?

Thanks very much for your answers

Comment: Why don't you install it with MiKTeX Package Manager? You wouldn't have fight with `dtx` files.

Comment: The MiKteX Package Manager is not able to connect with the network because I have protected (and very restrictive) connection. One solution should be to do the installation at home probably and to keep my MiKTeX portable version on my USB device (but I wanted to avoid this solution)

Comment: You could use a local repository with the package manager. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362443/2388

Comment: So I tried the solution of the comment given by Ulrike, when I go to MiKTeX Package Manager, Repository>Change Package Repository, I select the option Packages shall be installed from a directory, then I select my local repository, the synchronization seems to begin, but end up with a MiKTeX Problem Report: 'Couldn't resolve host name', which I don't understand in that case